# How to install ajaxControlToolKit.dll in gac

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two different version dll of ajaxcontroltoolkit  in a project, i can not put both in bin folder so i need to install them in gac. How to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add an assembly into the GAC, the assembly needs to be strongly named.
If you have the code, you can do it and then add it to the GAC.
If you don't have the code but the assembly itself, you still can strong name the assembly using the Assembly Linker :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx

> al /out:MyAssembly.dll MyModule.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk

Regards

Comment: You mean to say that If i have only dll then i can not add dll in GAC.
I don't think so. There must be a method to deploy dll in GAC.

Comment: If you don't want to believe me that's fine, but you CAN'T add an assembly to the GAC without a strong name.

Comment: Hey Markust, i wanted some more clarification of what you wrote above,
you wrote "If you have the code, you can do it and then add it to the GAC". so my question is suppose i have two dll with same name and i don't have code then what will happen? according to you because we don't have code so we can not add them into GAC.

Comment: If you don't have the code, you still can add a strong name to the assembly using the Assembly Linker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx. You will need to do it through command Line. Will update my answer to reflect this.